# Controller method call using ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework. I am trying to call controller method using AJAX function call on dropdown change event. My code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on('change', '#assettype_id', function(e) {
    var categoryval = $('#assettype_id :selected').val();
    // assettype_id is dropdown id. On change event of 
    // dropdown, controller method will be called

    myurl = 'http://mylocalsite/index.php/controllername/controllermethod/' + $.now();

    alert("category id = " + categoryval); // for testing
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        id: categoryval
      },
      url: myurl,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data1) {
        alert("inside ajax call"); // for testing
        $('#result').html("");
        // result is a div tag used to display result//
        $("#result").html(data1);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error');
      },
      complete: function(xhr, status) {
        alert("The request is complete!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This code is working perfectly for initial 2 or 3 change events of dropdown and getting new output but after 2 or 3 selection from dropdown, won't get new result like AJAX method is not working.

I have put 2 alerts for checking. `alert` with message 'category id =' is calling on every change event of dropdown but `alert` with message "inside ajax call" is not showing after 2 or 3 selections of dropdown even not going to error section of AJAX call.

I would like to know what is going wrong here? Thank you for you help.

Comment: Check the network tab of your browser developer tools. See if you are sending the requests and what response you get from the server.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I checked in developers tool. For successful ajax call it is making a new entry with status '200' but after making 2 or 3 selection, no new entry is showing in 'Network-XHR section'

Comment: Are you getting change event on dropdown change? have you checked by placing console.log?

Comment: Yes getting change event every time when i change selection in dropdown. Alert message with 'category id =' which showing current selection is working every time with new id

Comment: Does this happen in other browsers too? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Try `console.log(myurl)` instead of `alert("category id = " + categoryval);` before calling ajax. if Url is getting generated properly or not

Comment: Yes, it is happening with other browser too. I used chrome and firefox both but firefox working more properly than chrome however problem is same

Comment: For unsuccessful ajax call, i am getting following error in developer tool: 
             Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
        at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (0:170)
         at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
        at HTMLBodyElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: sharing screenshot of developer tool output: see open following link                                                                    https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/4/8/d3f31d9c4bc7082787e6e36d23dc4145-full.jpg                                                                                                                         As you can see in image, there are 4 successful ajax call but after another selection from dropdown it is showing some error

Comment: Also added console.log as suggested by Mr. Bhavik, as you can see different URL in image for successful ajax call.